# angular service with endpoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I just started Angular and I want to create a simple service that can generate data with my api.

I have a route that returns this :

```
/ranking/:id
```

returns a ranking from results in a video game

```
[
  { 
    position: 1,
    user: 1234,
    score: 150
  }, {
    position: 2,
    user: 5678,
    score: 100
  }
 ...
]
```

then

```
/users?ids=id1,id2,id3
```

returns an array of users

```
[
 {
  id: 1234,
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe'
 },
 ...
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a function that can display an array of objects with my users inside by combining the endpoints so I can get an object like this :

```
 [
  {
   position: 1,
   score: 150,
   firstName: 'John',
   lastName: 'Doe'
  },
  ...
 ]
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You need to provide more information on what your existing angular service looks like as well what you are using on the server side to send/retrieve data.

Comment: And also specify which angular version you are using

Comment: I'm using node.js, I don't have a particular angular service so far. I'm learning angular so I'm using an old project with routes that already exists. Like a small practice exercice.

Comment: as a side comment, why not to combine the arrays already on the server? Doing 1 network request is way better then doing two, especially, since you always have to request both ranking and users.

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt I'm using Angular 1.5

Comment: @VladimirM Yes I know. But it was a good exercice to learn how to manipulate my data as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help

```
first inject $q in your service, so you can execute two or more async calls at once.


var rankingsProm = $http.get('rankings endpoint');
var usersProm = $http.get('users endpoint');

$q.all([rankingsProm, usersProm]).then(function (responses) {
   console.log("result of $q.all", responses)
   // responses[0] => rankings and responses[1] => users
   console.log(mergeRankingWithUsers(responses[0], responses[1]))
})


function mergeRankingWithUsers (rankings, users) {
  var merged = rankings.map(function (ranking) {
    var index = users.findIndex(function (user) { return user.id === ranking.user; });
    ranking.firstName = index > -1 ? users[index].firstName : 'unknown';
    ranking.lastName = index > -1 ? users[index].lastName : 'unknown';
    return ranking;
  })
  return merged;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm having `ReferenceError: $q is not defined` does it means that I need to wrap the `$q.all` into `application.service(function($q))` and pass $q as a parameter  ?

Comment: yes Sir, it would be something like angular.module('somedule').service('YourServiceName', function ($q, $http) { // some code })

Comment: I'm having `angular is not defined` I'm just in a regular js file. 
`var rankingModule = angular.module('rankingModule', []);` it doesn't work like that ?

Comment: rankingModule.service('YourServiceName', function ($q, $http) { // some code })